# Why this equality holds?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, self-learning

Can you help me to see why the following equality holds? This is in page 310 of [Politis et al.(1997)](https://www.econ.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:ffffffff-935a-b0d6-0000-00007cdb20cb/joeOld.pdf)

[image]

where $\{r_n\},\{b_n\}$ are nonnegative sequences, $\delta>0$ a given constant, and $U'_{n,i}$ a sum of $b_n$ random variables. At first, I thought this came from multiply and divide strategy. Does it holds only with additional assumptions?

I do not see why $(r_nb_n)^{\frac{2+\delta}{2}+\frac{2}{2+\delta}}=1$.

Comment: What is $U_{n,i}'$?

Comment: @saulspatz I updated my question with more informations.

Comment: Stanford people making stupid mistakes. ;-)

Comment: @amsmath Just by curiosity, why did you highlight the Standford researcher? I don't know if there is an US' in-joke about it .

Comment: @CelineHarumi It's just that Stanford is considered a university with high quality. Here we see that the quality is not always horrendously good. ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $Var$-thing is exactly the same on both sides. So, we can divide by it. Then we are left with
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{r_n}E|U_{n,i}'|^{2+\delta} = \frac 1{r_n^{(2+\delta)/2}}\cdot \frac{1}{r_n^{2/(2+\delta)}b_n^{2/(2+\delta)}}\sum_{i=1}^{r_n}E|b_n^{-1/2}U_{n,i}'|^{2+\delta}.
$$
Now, $E(\cdot)$ is a linear function, so you can pull $(b_n^{-1/2})^{2+\delta} = 1/b_n^{(2+\delta)/2}$ out of it (I assume that $b_n$ is not random). So, we can divide by the sum and get
$$
1 = \frac 1{r_n^{(2+\delta)/2}}\cdot \frac{1}{r_n^{2/(2+\delta)}b_n^{2/(2+\delta)}}\cdot\frac 1{b_n^{(2+\delta)/2}} = \frac 1{(r_nb_n)^{\frac{2+\delta}2 + \frac 2{2+\delta}}},
$$
which is obviously false. I guess the guys on the paper had some problems with power laws.

Comment: There is no way for this equality. This paper was received and "revised", and was published in Journal of Econometrics. There are more things that I don't agree with this paper. I will ask in another question. Thanks

Comment: @CelineHarumi No prob.

Comment: I just posted the question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394312/joining-pieces-to-find-a-correct-proof-central-limit-theorem   Please, take a look, if you can.