# Joining pieces to find a correct proof (Central Limit Theorem)

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, self-learning

In [Politis et al. (1997)](https://www.econ.uzh.ch/dam/jcr:ffffffff-935a-b0d6-0000-00007cdb20cb/joeOld.pdf)'s proof of Theorem A.1 (specifically, pages 309-310), there are issues that I'm trying to clarify. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3394208/why-this-equality-holds) previous post, it is clear that the following equality does not hold:

[image]

With the correct powers, the expression does not converges to zero (and the proof breaks down). Now, take a look at the sketch of the proof:
[image]

As far as I understand, Step $1$ should be the Lyapunov's condition. I will state the Lyapunov's Central Limit Theorem.

> Suppose that $\{X_i\}$ is a sequence of independent random variables
>   such that, for each $i$, $E(X_i)=\mu_i<\infty$ and $
>  Var(X_i)=\sigma_i^2<\infty$. Define $s_n^2=\sum_{k=1}^n \sigma_k^2$.
>   If there exists $\delta>0$ so that $\mid X_i\mid^{2+\delta}$ are
>   integrable and the Lyaponov's condition holds, i.e.,
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{s_n^{2+\delta}}\sum_{k=1}^n E[\mid
>  X_k-\mu_k\mid^{2+\delta}]=0,$$    then    $$\frac{1}{s_n}\sum_{k=1}^n
>  (X_k-\mu_k)\overset{d}{\to} N(0,1).$$

Assume that $\{U'_{n,i}\}_{i=1}^{r_n}$ are zero mean random variables  satisfying the moment conditions of the theorem. I believe that Step $1$ should be replaced by 
$$\bigg[Var\bigg(\sum_{k=1}^{r_n} U'_{n,i}\bigg)\bigg]^{-(2+\delta)/2}\sum_{i=1}^{r_n} E\mid U'_{n,i}\mid^{2+\delta}\to 0, n\to\infty$$
since $\big[Var\big(\sum_{k=1}^{r_n} U'_{n,i}\big)\big]^{-(2+\delta)/2}=\big[\sum_{k=1}^{r_n} Var(U'_{n,i})\big]^{-(2+\delta)/2}:=\big[s_n^2\big]^{-(2+\delta)/2}=1/s_n^{2+\delta}$. Doing so, I can easily show the convergence of the term of Step $1$, using exactly the same powers that the author used.

To conclude, I believe the authors typed the power of the variance term wrong.

Do you agree with me?